# Why below C program gives output?

Tags: c, types, char, integer

Why output of below C code gives number when int datatype value is assigned as character

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int i= '5';
printf("%d",i);
return 0;
}
```

How its output is 53

Comment: the character `'5'` does not have integer value 5. Look up "ASCII".

Comment: You probably wanted `int i= 5;`.

Comment: Character constants actually have integer type. It is perfectly fine to print as integer. Char `'5'` has ASCII value `0x35` == `53`

Answer (score 2):

Because `char` is an **integer** type.

For human convenience, you can use letters instead of their codes.
Most modern systems use ASCII codes.

`'5'` is 53 in ASCII

```
Dec     Hex Binary      HTML    Char    Description
0       00  00000000    &#0;    NUL     Null
1       01  00000001    &#1;    SOH     Start of Header
2       02  00000010    &#2;    STX     Start of Text
3       03  00000011    &#3;    ETX     End of Text
4       04  00000100    &#4;    EOT     End of Transmission
5       05  00000101    &#5;    ENQ     Enquiry
6       06  00000110    &#6;    ACK     Acknowledge
7       07  00000111    &#7;    BEL     Bell
8       08  00001000    &#8;    BS  Backspace
9       09  00001001    &#9;    HT  Horizontal Tab
10      0A  00001010    &#10;   LF  Line Feed
11      0B  00001011    &#11;   VT  Vertical Tab
12      0C  00001100    &#12;   FF  Form Feed
13      0D  00001101    &#13;   CR  Carriage Return
14      0E  00001110    &#14;   SO  Shift Out
15      0F  00001111    &#15;   SI  Shift In
16      10  00010000    &#16;   DLE     Data Link Escape
17      11  00010001    &#17;   DC1     Device Control 1
18      12  00010010    &#18;   DC2     Device Control 2
19      13  00010011    &#19;   DC3     Device Control 3
20      14  00010100    &#20;   DC4     Device Control 4
21      15  00010101    &#21;   NAK     Negative Acknowledge
22      16  00010110    &#22;   SYN     Synchronize
23      17  00010111    &#23;   ETB     End of Transmission Block
24      18  00011000    &#24;   CAN     Cancel
25      19  00011001    &#25;   EM  End of Medium
26      1A  00011010    &#26;   SUB     Substitute
27      1B  00011011    &#27;   ESC     Escape
28      1C  00011100    &#28;   FS  File Separator
29      1D  00011101    &#29;   GS  Group Separator
30      1E  00011110    &#30;   RS  Record Separator
31      1F  00011111    &#31;   US  Unit Separator
32      20  00100000    &#32;   space   Space
33      21  00100001    &#33;   !   Exclamation mark
34      22  00100010    &#34;   "   Double quote
35      23  00100011    &#35;   #   Number
36      24  00100100    &#36;   $   Dollar sign
37      25  00100101    &#37;   %   Percent
38      26  00100110    &#38;   &   Ampersand
39      27  00100111    &#39;   '   Single quote
40      28  00101000    &#40;   (   Left parenthesis
41      29  00101001    &#41;   )   Right parenthesis
42      2A  00101010    &#42;   *   Asterisk
43      2B  00101011    &#43;   +   Plus
44      2C  00101100    &#44;   ,   Comma
45      2D  00101101    &#45;   -   Minus
46      2E  00101110    &#46;   .   Period
47      2F  00101111    &#47;   /   Slash
48      30  00110000    &#48;   0   Zero
49      31  00110001    &#49;   1   One
50      32  00110010    &#50;   2   Two
51      33  00110011    &#51;   3   Three
52      34  00110100    &#52;   4   Four
53      35  00110101    &#53;   5   Five
54      36  00110110    &#54;   6   Six
55      37  00110111    &#55;   7   Seven
56      38  00111000    &#56;   8   Eight
57      39  00111001    &#57;   9   Nine
58      3A  00111010    &#58;   :   Colon
59      3B  00111011    &#59;   ;   Semicolon
60      3C  00111100    &#60;   <   Less than
61      3D  00111101    &#61;   =   Equality sign
62      3E  00111110    &#62;   >   Greater than
63      3F  00111111    &#63;   ?   Question mark
64      40  01000000    &#64;   @   At sign
65      41  01000001    &#65;   A   Capital A
66      42  01000010    &#66;   B   Capital B
67      43  01000011    &#67;   C   Capital C
68      44  01000100    &#68;   D   Capital D
69      45  01000101    &#69;   E   Capital E
70      46  01000110    &#70;   F   Capital F
71      47  01000111    &#71;   G   Capital G
72      48  01001000    &#72;   H   Capital H
73      49  01001001    &#73;   I   Capital I
74      4A  01001010    &#74;   J   Capital J
75      4B  01001011    &#75;   K   Capital K
76      4C  01001100    &#76;   L   Capital L
77      4D  01001101    &#77;   M   Capital M
78      4E  01001110    &#78;   N   Capital N
79      4F  01001111    &#79;   O   Capital O
80      50  01010000    &#80;   P   Capital P
81      51  01010001    &#81;   Q   Capital Q
82      52  01010010    &#82;   R   Capital R
83      53  01010011    &#83;   S   Capital S
84      54  01010100    &#84;   T   Capital T
85      55  01010101    &#85;   U   Capital U
86      56  01010110    &#86;   V   Capital V
87      57  01010111    &#87;   W   Capital W
88      58  01011000    &#88;   X   Capital X
89      59  01011001    &#89;   Y   Capital Y
90      5A  01011010    &#90;   Z   Capital Z
91      5B  01011011    &#91;   [   Left square bracket
92      5C  01011100    &#92;   \   Backslash
93      5D  01011101    &#93;   ]   Right square bracket
94      5E  01011110    &#94;   ^   Caret / circumflex
95      5F  01011111    &#95;   _   Underscore
96      60  01100000    &#96;   `   Grave / accent
97      61  01100001    &#97;   a   Small a
98      62  01100010    &#98;   b   Small b
99      63  01100011    &#99;   c   Small c
100     64  01100100    &#100;  d   Small d
101     65  01100101    &#101;  e   Small e
102     66  01100110    &#102;  f   Small f
103     67  01100111    &#103;  g   Small g
104     68  01101000    &#104;  h   Small h
105     69  01101001    &#105;  i   Small i
106     6A  01101010    &#106;  j   Small j
107     6B  01101011    &#107;  k   Small k
108     6C  01101100    &#108;  l   Small l
109     6D  01101101    &#109;  m   Small m
110     6E  01101110    &#110;  n   Small n
111     6F  01101111    &#111;  o   Small o
112     70  01110000    &#112;  p   Small p
113     71  01110001    &#113;  q   Small q
114     72  01110010    &#114;  r   Small r
115     73  01110011    &#115;  s   Small s
116     74  01110100    &#116;  t   Small t
117     75  01110101    &#117;  u   Small u
118     76  01110110    &#118;  v   Small v
119     77  01110111    &#119;  w   Small w
120     78  01111000    &#120;  x   Small x
121     79  01111001    &#121;  y   Small y
122     7A  01111010    &#122;  z   Small z
123     7B  01111011    &#123;  {   Left curly bracket
124     7C  01111100    &#124;  |   Vertical bar
125     7D  01111101    &#125;  }   Right curly bracket
126     7E  01111110    &#126;  ~   Tilde
127     7F  01111111    &#127;  DEL Delete
```

Table (C) https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes in C mean it is a Character (similar to a String).

```
i = '5';
```

assigns ASCII character "5" to variable `i`.
And ASCII character 5 is encoded as value `53`.

If you want integer 5, it would be:

```
int i = 5;  // Note the lack of quotes.
```